# Fresh Wordpress install on Amazon Linux EC2...can't delete and reinstall

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just recently started by creating a EC2 instance on AWS.  I used the Amazon Linux package.  I changed the PHP settings to include the ability to upload files larger than 200MB.  Got phpinfo.php working.  Installed phpMyAdmin.  Everything looked good.

Next, I installed Wordpress. It worked great. Then I tried installing a theme. Worked great. Then I started installing some plugins for that theme. Something made the site crash. I tried a few things, but since I couldn't go to the sites Wordpress Admin panel, it seemed hopeless. So I decided to start from scratch. I deleted the html directory (including wp-content) and dropped all the wordpress tables. I moved a fresh copy of Wordpress into the html directory, reconfigured the config.php file, and it recreated the Wordpress tables in the database. Seems to work great. When I try to upload a theme, it says:

```
Connection Information
To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.
```

I noticed that wp-content didn't have a uploads directory, so I created one. That seemed to let me upload the theme, but it showed up as a media file. I moved it to the theme directory and that worked. But when I tried to upload a plugin, I got the same message as a above.

What happened when I deleted everything? Or rather, where was information stored that when I reinstalled Wordpress, it didn't create a uploads directory?  I am fine with reinstalling Wordpress from scratch, but I don't want to reinstall the whole LAMP stack or redo the AWS instance.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your web server doesn't have the proper permissions to write to your content directory.

The WordPress Codex has some good info for [proper file and directory permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions). Ideally, all files should have `644` permissions, and all directories should be `755` (no higher).

If you're still running into issues adding plugins and updating WordPress, you should heed the advice of the following (so that you don't have to enter FTP details into WordPress each time):

> Any file that needs write access from WordPress **should be writable by the web server**. If your hosting set up requires it, that may mean those files need to be group-owned by the user account used by the web server process.